# Calling a javascript function in different ways

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this

Consider I have a function as:

```
function test1() {
  this.x= 10;
  this.fun = function() {
   return function() {
   console.log(this.x);
  };
 };
}


var obj = new test1();
var returnFun = obj.fun();
```

There are 2 ways of calling this function:

```
returnFun();
```

and

```
returnFun.call(obj);
```

why is it that the first method is not recommendable and what will be the value for **"this"** in two different contexts?
Will `var obj = new test1();` statement create a new object and set the value of `"this"` as prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is it that the first method (`returnFun();`) is not recommendable?

There's nothing wrong with that method at all.

> what will be the value for "this" in two different contexts?

The value of `this` in the first example will be the outer scope the function was defined in, which would be the `window`.

To change the scope of `this` programmatically, use either the [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods, as you have done in the second example. This means that for the second example, `this` in the function would refer to the `obj` variable.

Comment: value of "this" is not the same In both the calls , in the case :returnFun.call(obj); the value of "this" is "obj"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I have a clarification, when you say in the first example , "this" will be the outer scope the function was defined in , that means if I put it in a function A(){ returnFun() ; } will "this" be the same as "this" of A()?